# merge dataframes by date after persision reduced

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

Thank you for looking at this....

Need to reduce the precision of IoT Sensor data timestamps and merge.

I have two csv files with the following data

CSV-1

```
datetime,temperature
2017-06-13 22:20:11.309,82.4
2017-06-13 22:19:54.004,82.4
2017-06-13 22:19:36.661,82.4
2017-06-13 22:19:19.359,82.4
```

CSV-2

```
datetime,humidity
2017-06-13 22:07:30.723,63.0
2017-06-13 22:07:13.448,63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:56.115,63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:38.806,63.0
```

Note that the datetime entries are to the millisecond. I am using the following code to reduce precision to seconds.

```
ugt = pd.read_csv('ugt.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
ugh = pd.read_csv('ugh.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

ugt.index = ugt.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))
ugh.index = ugh.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))
```

That produces the following dataframes:

```
                     temperature
datetime                        
2017-06-13 22:06:57         82.4 <---
2017-06-13 22:06:37         82.4
2017-06-13 22:06:20         82.4
2017-06-13 22:06:03         82.0 <---

                 humidity
datetime                     
2017-06-13 22:06:57      63.0 <---
2017-06-13 22:06:38      63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:21      63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:03      63.0 <---
```

Note that some of the timestamps match (see  <---) to the second, others do not. this is due to limitations of the various sensors ability to perform readings. There is no consistently to frequency.

Then we create a master dataframe that are populated with rows for ever second of the day for the time period that we collected data from all the sensors.

```
                     temperature  humidity
2017-04-25 12:00:00            0         0
2017-04-25 12:00:01            0         0
2017-04-25 12:00:02            0         0
2017-04-25 12:00:03            0         0
2017-04-25 12:00:04            0         0
```

We can not figure out how to use pandas concat, merge, append the two csv files into the master dataframe based on datetime. What we want is the following:

```
                     temperature  humidity
2017-04-25 12:00:00            0         0
2017-04-25 12:00:01            82.0      0
2017-04-25 12:00:02            0         44.0
2017-04-25 12:00:03            0         0
2017-04-25 12:00:04            82.0      44.0
2017-04-25 12:00:05            0         0
2017-04-25 12:00:06            82.0      0
2017-04-25 12:00:07            0         0
2017-04-25 12:00:08            82.0      44.0
```

There are additional sensors we'll add in the future.... light, CO2, so almost every second will eventually have a column with data in it.

We also want to perform some analysis on how frequency various sensors are able to collect data and their accuracy, hence the use of the master dataframe.

You all rock! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need to create the master dataframe? It seems like it will be quite sparse and sounds like it will be a lot of loops to fill it (although there might be some pandas ways of working around it).

Comment: We could live with a merge of the two csv files to include only entries (skip seconds with no values of any sensor), but the master DF with every second, even if empty, would allow us to do easier analysis on how frequently the sensors are able to collect data, and how accurate it can do so. Would welcome your thoughts

Comment: Ok I proposed a solution with a master dataframe, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

temp (temperature) dataframe:

```
                 datetime  temperature
0  2017-06-13 22:20:11.309         82.4
1  2017-06-13 22:19:54.004         82.4
2  2017-06-13 22:19:36.661         82.4
3  2017-06-13 22:19:19.359         82.4
```

humid dataframe:

```
                 datetime  humidity
0  2017-06-13 22:07:30.723      63.0
1  2017-06-13 22:07:13.448      63.0
2  2017-06-13 22:06:56.115      63.0
3  2017-06-13 22:06:38.806      63.0



temp.datetime = pd.to_datetime(temp.datetime) #convert to datetime dtype
temp.set_index('datetime', inplace=True) #make it the index
temp.index = temp.index.round('S') #and now round to the second
```

Now the temp dataframe looks like:

```
                     temperature
datetime                        
2017-06-13 22:20:11         82.4
2017-06-13 22:19:54         82.4
2017-06-13 22:19:37         82.4
2017-06-13 22:19:19         82.4
```

Do the same for humid df:

```
humid.datetime = pd.to_datetime(humid.datetime) 
humi.set_index('datetime', inplace=True) 
humid.index = humid.index.round('S')
```

Now humid is:

```
                     humidity
datetime                     
2017-06-13 22:07:31      63.0
2017-06-13 22:07:13      63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:56      63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:39      63.0
```

Reindex temp, replace the dates as you like:

```
temp = temp.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2017-06-13 22:00', end='2017-06-13 22:20', freq='S'))
temp.head()

                     temperature
2017-06-13 22:00:00          NaN
2017-06-13 22:00:01          NaN
2017-06-13 22:00:02          NaN
2017-06-13 22:00:03          NaN
2017-06-13 22:00:04          NaN
```

And now left join:

```
out = pd.merge(temp, humid, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')

out.head():
                     temperature  humidity
2017-06-13 22:00:00          NaN       NaN
2017-06-13 22:00:01          NaN       NaN
2017-06-13 22:00:02          NaN       NaN
2017-06-13 22:00:03          NaN       NaN
2017-06-13 22:00:04          NaN       NaN
```

Make sure this actually worked:

```
out.loc['2017-06-13 22:07:31']
                     temperature  humidity
2017-06-13 22:07:31          NaN      63.0
```

Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution to your problem would be to use the pd.join().

```
df_joined = ugt.join(ugh, how='outer')

                      temperature    humidity                     
2017-06-13 22:06:03          82.0    63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:20          82.4    NaN
2017-06-13 22:06:21           NaN    63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:37          82.4    NaN
2017-06-13 22:06:38           NaN    63.0
2017-06-13 22:06:57          82.4    63.0
```

After the join fill the master dataframe by looping through the joined dataframe and using the index to assing to each row:

```
for index, row in df_joined.iterrows():
    df_master.loc[index,'humidity'] = row['humidity']
    df_master.loc[index,'temperature'] = row['temperature']
```

I don't have the output because I didn't build a master dataframe, but it should work

Comment: The first part of this answer was very helpful. The second part of this answer took timed out as their was 90,000 rows to update.

Comment: Yes I wouldn't recommend using a master data frame. I would work around it but it's hard to say how since I don't know your specific requirements. Something like if you can't find an entry for that time then it's NaN when doing the analysis.